# add function to a string

Tags: php, string

I need to add one of my functions to the following code:

```
$string = '<div class="row">;
<label class="col1">State or Province</label>
<span class="col2"><select name="billing[state]" class="mid2" onChange="ShopperPress_ChangeState_Value(this.valu e)">';
$string .= '<option value="0">-------- Select ----------</option>';
```

Where text is being printed, such as "State or Province", I need to add the function that will connect to my language file to display that text in different languages. I would normally replace such text with the following:

```
<?php echo SPEC($GLOBALS['_LANG']['State or Province']) ?>
```

But I can't get the syntax right amongst the other PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<div class="row">;
<label class="col1">' . SPEC($GLOBALS['_LANG']['State or Province']). '</label>
<span class="col2"><select name="billing[state]" class="mid2" onChange="ShopperPress_ChangeState_Value(this.valu e)">';
$string .= '<option value="0">-------- Select ----------</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax was a bit confusing, but it looks like you'd just need to do this:

```
<label class="col1">' . SPEC($GLOBALS['_LANG']['State or Province']) . '</label>
```